# Map coordinates to camera coordinates

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a tiled map which is 3 times higher than camera. When I press on a tile, I want an actor on that tile to show up. This works if camera is not moved. If I move camera a little bit up, so the tile coordinates are greater then camera coordinates, actor is placed offscreen. Is there a way to get tile coordinates so they wil fit the camera coordinates

[image]

Im using libgdx if it helps.

Comment: It depends a bit on how you are drawing everything. It sounds like you are not using the same projection matrix on your map and your actor. It would help if you could post some code

Comment: What have you tried so far to fix this? It could be that the coords you pick with the mouse don't account for camera movement. It could be that the problem is in how you render the board and actor with respect to the camera. It could be that it's just a matter of a minus where there should be a plus. There's just no way to know. More info please?

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the Camera `unproject(Vector3 screenCoords)` method. This will translate the point clicked on the screen to the 'world' point.

This should allow you to the tile X,Y and then translate to the correct tile.